# Rails 4 joins + where not generating correct SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider this example:

```
class Notification::User
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :nullify
end

class Notification::Address
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Executing this `addresses.joins(:user).where(user: {name: 'Test'}).to_sql` produces this:

```
SELECT `notification_addresses`.* FROM `notification_addresses` 
INNER JOIN `notification_users` ON `notification_users`.`id` 
= `notification_addresses`.`user_id` 
WHERE `notification_users`.`name` = 'Test'
```

Which is the correct output produced, but only with the `gem 'squeel'` included. I am using old rails version `4.2.10` and I want to get rid of `gem 'squeel'` before upgrading to rails 5.

This is the generated of the same code SQL when I actually get rid of the `gem 'squeel'` :

```
SELECT `notification_addresses`.* FROM `notification_addresses` 
INNER JOIN `notification_users` ON `notification_users`.`id` 
= `notification_addresses`.`user_id` 
WHERE `user`.`name` = 'Test'
```

Which is not a correct SQL, to be exact this part `WHERE "user"."name" = 'Test'` and it should be `users` like in the first example. What is going on here? Is my only option this:

```
addresses.joins(:user).where('notification_users.name = ?', 'Test'})
addresses.joins(:user).where(notification_users: { name: 'Test'})
```

In this rails version?

Comment: Maybe, I think later versions are smarter here. What does `.where(users: {name: 'Test'})` give you?

Comment: try this: `.where(notification_users: {name: 'Test'})`

Comment: @max yes later versions are smarter. But that's not how the relation is called, the relation is called `:user` on the model. This is what the controller passes on here `{user: {name: 'Test'}}` and it works with squeel. BUT I'm trying to remove it and pass the same filters from the controller, and it's failing in this case.

Comment: @khiav reoy pretty much same answer is for you, that does work but still I m getting `{user: {name: 'Test'}}` from the caller (controller in this case)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `where({user: {name: 'Test'}})` specifies the table name of `user` not the relationship `user`. You can use merge:

`addresses.joins(:user).merge(NotificationUser.where(name: 'Test'))`